# How to get table from the link using python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i am trying to parse the table from the link. i tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.find_all(class_='MsoNormalTable'):
    print(table)
```

But can't get So, can you guide me, how do i parse table using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just do this? I can't read the language but it might be right.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
middleTable = soup.find('table', class_='MsoNormalTable')
rows = middleTable.findAll('tr')
for eachRow in rows:
    print(eachRow.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
soup.find_all("table", {"class": "MsoNormalTable"})
```

you should specify the tag and to access through attribute it should be passed in dictionary

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.